# Eclipse gives errors I can't understand

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to run some unit tests on a project that has already been developed. I pulled it on to my system into the git repositories and then built it on the command line. It all succeeded and all the tests run, however, inside eclipse I seem to be getting an error (I think a data error rather than a Java error).

This is what I think the error message is:

> org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: Duplicate entry '11' for key 'line_item_ref_number_unique'; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '11' for key 'line_item_ref_number_unique'

I am not very good at debugging and would struggle to get to the problem that way.
I will post more code on at request but do not want to bombard the question area with potential unnecessary code.

This might not be very helpful what I have said so far but anyone got any solutions or advice?

Comment: Your error looks like it came from hibernate. So you have a duplicate line in your database which wasn't there when you ran the first test. Perhaps you should start with a clean database?

Comment: @RealSkeptic how do i clean the database? i am using my sql

Comment: You should check with whoever programmed this project (or if there is documentation). Many times, there will be a build option to "clean". I can't help you further as I don't know the project. Of course, if it's a production database, **don't** clean it.

Answer (score 1):

```
 org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: 
 Duplicate entry '11' for key 'line_item_ref_number_unique'
```

In your database `line_item_ref_number_unique` is unique key column and you are trying to add duplicate entry in that column so it is giving you `ConstraintViolationException`.

don't consider this error as eclipse error it is hibernate exception.
You have to check what you are inserting in your database? and why it is duplicate entry?

Answer (score 0):

You are facing issue ConstraintViolationException its not releated to eclipse environment.

```
Nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException
```

Please review your database entries and code which is trying to add values.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to insert data with primary key which is already in the database or trying to entry duplicate data in unique field. Change that piece of code.

For testing purpose you can configure hibernate to re-create the schema every time app start by adding this line in your hibernate config file.

```
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto = create | create-drop
```